# While using the AngularJS based Treeview (no jQuery), how to set the data-node-label with the data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, treeview

Here is my jsfidder: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0n1ydream/4uk7usgk/).

I'm trying to use the [AngularJS Treeview](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview) and it's the [official demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/b9Pnw/) .

```
<div
  data-angular-treeview="true"
  data-tree-model="data"
  data-node-id="value"
  data-node-label="value.artifactId"
  data-node-children="children" >
</div>
```

I want to set the node name with the data in value. For example, the name of node

`"value": {artifactId": "mock", "groupId": "com.myproject", "scope": "compile", "type": "jar", "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"}`
should be `mock.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` . I want to know how to set the value of the `data-node-label`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the feeding JSON format as below.
I have taken only few records just to show the syntax.

```
{
    "roleName" : "sts.api", 
    "roleId" : "com.myproject.sts", 
    "scope": "compile",
    "type": "jar",
    "version": "0.0.7-SNAPSHOT",
    "children" : []
},  
{
    "roleName" : "simbacall.api", 
    "roleId" : "com.myproject.simba", 
    "scope": "compile",
    "type": "jar",
    "version": "1.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    "children" : [
        {
            "roleName" : "javax.ws.rs-api", 
            "roleId" : "javax.ws.rs", 
            "scope": "compile",
            "type": "jar",
            "version": "2.0",
            "children" : []
        },
        {
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: The problem is that I can not change the JSON format, so I want to know how to fix this with the current format...